# How to insert a js array into html using innerHTML?

Tags: innerhtml

In order to build a more clean code, i would like to delete an unordered list from html file and insert instead a js array using innerHTML. The problem is that i am new to html/css/js and I have a lot of difficulties in typing the correct syntax and understanding the logic.

In my html file i had a div with id="listOfBeaches "containing a list with beaches. if i delete the ul and I try to insert instead a js array i don't get any result.

```
<div id="listOfBeaches"> 
    <ul>
        <li><h3><a href="./Horseshoe.html"target="_blank">Horseshoe Bay</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="./Trunk-bay.html"target="_blank">Trunk BAy</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="./El-Nido.html"target="_blank">El Nido</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="./Rheeti-Rah.html"target="_blank">Reethi Rah</a></h3></li>
        <li><h3><a href="./Maundays-BAy.html"target="_blank">Maundays Bay</a></h3></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I try to replace this html code with the following js code

```
let beaches= [
    {
      name: 'Horseshoe Bay',
      url: './Horseshoe.html',
    },
    {
      nume: 'Trunk BAy',
      url: './Trunk-bay.html',
    },
    {
        name: 'El Nido',
        url: './El-Nido.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'Reethi Rah',
        url: './Rheeti-Rah.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'Maundays Bay',
        url: './Maundays-BAy.html'
    }
  ];


  let myBeaches = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++){
    myBeaches = beaches[i].name;
  }

  document.getElementById('listOfBeaches').innerHTML(myBeaches);
```

The result should be a list of beaches at the top of my webpage 
Can I get any help from you guys?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to look at the output of `document.getElementById('listOfBeaches').innnerHTML` you would see that it would contain

> ```
> <ul>
>     <li><h3><a href="./Horseshoe.html"target="_blank">Horseshoe Bay</a></h3></li>
>     <li><h3><a href="./Trunk-bay.html"target="_blank">Trunk BAy</a></h3></li>
>     <li><h3><a href="./El-Nido.html"target="_blank">El Nido</a></h3></li>
>     <li><h3><a href="./Rheeti-Rah.html"target="_blank">Reethi Rah</a></h3></li>
>     <li><h3><a href="./Maundays-BAy.html"target="_blank">Maundays Bay</a></h3></li>
> </ul>
> ```

So as such, you'll need to build up a similar html entry if you want to replace it using the innerHtml method.  You could do something as such:

https://jsfiddle.net/nshe1qL8/